# How to make a State Transition Table for an NFA?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have done creating the Transition Table for a DFA by using a two dimensions array. For example, to store 10 states and two transitions.

```
transition = new int[10][2];
```

However, For the NFA, we have many possible transitions to go. The example below, you can go to S2 or S3 when the value 0 is coming. So, I don't know which structure of Java that I should use.

I am trying to create the Table for an NFA for a day but all the ways that I have done are so complicated. For example using, Hashtable, Set, etc.

Could you please share an example of code or any ideas?

[image: Table for an NFA]

Comment: You can use an ArrayList to represent the result returned from the delta function.

Comment: @MarounMaroun  I'm sorry. I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bitset for each state, and use a bitwise or `|` for each transition.  For example, S1 = 001, S2 = 010, and S3 = 100.  Now S2 | S3 = 110, so your {S2, S3} transition is 110.  This allows for up to 32 states if represented by an int or 64 states if represented by a long; for more states (or for easier-to-use bitwise operations), use a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

Incidentally, ANY NFA can be converted to a DFA, see e.g. http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/390teched/regular/fa/nfa-2-dfa.html for a tutorial, so that may be another option depending on what you're trying to do here.